# dequeueReusableCell causes text to change color

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uicollectionview

I've got a collection view and I'm using a custom class for the cells. Each cell has two text view, chapterTitleTextView and chapterBodyTextView. I've added placeholders to both text views like so:

```
class CustomWriterPageCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    // When the user taps on a text view
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    
        if textView.textColor == .gray {
        
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    // When the user taps out of a text view or taps on the done button in the toolbar
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    
        // If the chapter title text view is empty
        if chapterTitleTextView.text.isEmpty {
        
            chapterTitleTextView.text = "Chapter Title"
            chapterTitleTextView.textColor = .gray
        
        }
        // If the chapter body text view is empty
        if chapterBodyTextView.text.isEmpty {
        
            chapterBodyTextView.text = "Chapter Body"
            chapterBodyTextView.textColor = .gray
        
        }
    }
}
```

How this works is that, the text color is initially gray and there is some text, when the user taps on the text view, the color changes to black and the text in the text view is removed.

Now there is this problem with using dequeueReusableCell, it’s that it reuses the cells, this caused problem number 1: Whatever I type on the text view in the first cell appears on the 4th cell, to solve this problem I had to create 2 global lists to hold whatever I type and this gets displayed in the text views of the cells, here’s the code:

Global Lists:

```
var chapterTitleText = Array(repeating: "", count: 4) // To store the chapter title text
var chapterBodyText = Array(repeating: "", count: 4) // To store the chapter body text
```

**The following code snippet is inside the textViewDidEndEditing from earlier**

```
// Append the chapter body text to the chapterBodyText array
let titleText = chapterTitleTextView.text
let titleRow = textView.tag //This the indexPath.row
chapterTitleText[titleRow] = titleText!
    
// Append the chapter title text to the chapterTitleText array
let bodyText = chapterBodyTextView.text
let bodyRow = textView.tag
chapterBodyText[bodyRow] = bodyText!
```

**And in cellForItemAt:**

```
cell.chapterBodyTextView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.chapterTitleTextView.tag = indexPath.row
        
cell.chapterTitleTextView.text = chapterTitleText[indexPath.row]
cell.chapterBodyTextView.text = chapterBodyText[indexPath.row]
```

This got rid of problem number 1 (text in the text views duplicating). But then I got a new problem, remember the placeholder text I was talking about? When I type something in the one of the textviews of the first cell, the text color of the text view in the fourth cell changes.

Here is a GIF replicating the problem:

[image: Video replicating the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your chain of questions, I suggest you to do this every time you're dealing with `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

Define a method in your cell class and take whatever data it needs to display itself as arguments:

```
func configure(text : String?) { //text is optional here which means it can be nil.
//However, from my previous answer you can replace it with an empty string condition.

    if let txt = text { //or if text != "" 
        self.chapterTitleTextView.text = txt
        self.chapterTitleTextView.text.textColor = .black
    }
    else {// As others mentioned make sure to always handle else because cells are reusable.
        self.chapterTitleTextView.text = "Chapter Title"
        self.chapterTitleTextView.text.textColor = .gray
    }

}
```

The intuition behind reusable cells are that since they are reusable, you should reconfigure them completely and not to expect that the configuration is saved or attached to the cell.

Now, in the `cellForItemAt`:

```
 let cell = ...
 cell.configure(text : chapterTitleText[indexPath.row])
```

And remember, in this way, you do not need to define a global array. As I've told you previously, this array need to be only defined in your Controller and your cell does not need to know about it. Your cell only needs to know about one index of that array which is passed through `configure` function.
Although that global array will work, I'm talking about propriety in coding.

Comment your problems with this approach(if any), I will try to answer with patience but don't expect a (copy-paste)able code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the reuse mechanism of the `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`. Since you only update the color in one way, collection "remembers" previous color and upon new cell recreates its previous state. You have two basic solutions here.

**First** is to update cell state for both cases like:

```
if myCondition == true {
  color = UIColor.gray
} else {
  color = UIColor.black
}
```

**Second** is to utilize `prepareForReuse` method of the `UICollectionViewCell`

```
func prepareForReuse() {
  // code that resets state of your cell to default 
}
```

Method description in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)

Comment: Hey, I've tried this, but It updates all the cells, anyway we could specify the cell?

Comment: The problem with placeholder most likely comes from your conditions `if chapterTitleTextView.text.isEmpty ` check if you're playing around with `becomeFirstResponder` on the textView and whether it's called before you set your text in `cellForRow` or after